# Flask-Login logs me in, but whenever I do a GET request, immediately logs me out again

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to build a web app using Flask. My front page (/) checks to see if anyone is logged in and if they are not, displays a form asking for username and password. Whne the user submits the from, these credentials are validated, and if valid a user object is created and sent to flask_login using its `login_user` function:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def front():
    tem = jinjaEnv.get_template("front_page.html")
    msg = "(no message)"
    if request.method=='POST':
        un = request.form['username']
        pw = request.form['password']
        user = modsal.getUser(un, pw)
        if user.is_authenticated:
            login_user(user)
            msg = ("<span style='color:#080; background:#efe;'>"
                   "<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> "
                   "You are logged in</span>")
        else:
            msg = ("<span style='color:#800; background:#fee;'>"
                   "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i> "
                   "login failed</span>")
    #//if
    h = tem.render(
        msg = msg,
    )
    return h
```

This works fine, and the user is logged in.

However, when I do a GET request to another page (or even the same one), flask-login logs me out. I have a `user_loader` callback, but it isn't being called by flask_login:

```
@loginManager.user_loader
def load_user(userId):
    """ returns a user object (for Flask_login).
    Given a userId (which is the username), returns an Engineer object
    (if it was a valid user), or None if not.
    @return Engineer|None
    """
    pr("%s-=-=- userId=%r -=-=-%s",
       termcolours.TermColours.MAGENTA,
       userId,
       termcolours.TermColours.NORMAL)
    from modsal import session, Engineer
    u = session.query(Engineer).filter(
        Engineer.username == username).one_or_none()

    # Note that if a user wasn't found, (u) will be None
    # here, which is what loginManager wants.
    return u
```

(Note that `pr()` prints debugging code to stderr.)

I wrote some debugging code to see what's going on. Before every request, this prints the session cookie:

```
@app.before_request
def checkSessionCookie():
    sessionStr = request.cookies.get('session_8210')
    decoded = decookie.decodeCookie(sessionStr)
    pr("%s***** decoded=%s%s",
       termcolours.TermColours.MAGENTA,
       decoded,
       termcolours.TermColours.NORMAL)
```

In my Jinja2 templates, I have a banner at the top of every page showing the username of the logged in user. This is implemented by calling `currentUserName()`, which returns a string containing the user name, or `""` if none:

```
def currentUserName():
    pr("%s current_user=%s %s",
        termcolours.TermColours.RED,
        current_user,
        termcolours.TermColours.NORMAL)
    if (not current_user) or current_user.is_anonymous:
        prvars("current_user")
        return ""
    try:
        un = str(current_user.username)
        prvars("un")
        return un
    except:
        return ""
jinjaEnv.globals['currentUserName'] = currentUserName
```

Note that this function also prints out debugging code when executing.

When I log in with a username of Mike and then do a GET / request, my stderr looks like this:

```
checkSessionCookie():113: ***** decoded={"_fresh":true,"_id":{" b":"MDY5N2MyNDhmZGU4YWVmZmE5NzMzNjEwODQwYmE2NWNhMmU2YzI4MDRiMWZlMmRiNmFhYjg2MmE5NDMyMGY2Y2RiYjBjMTNjOWYzMjE3ODk0YWVmMDk1YjA2ZWJlZjkyNmQ3MDE1MDdkZjI2MDRhNzg2MTI1NzFkOTU0MmJkM2M="},"csrf_token":{" b":"MTVlNGY4MDBjNWQwNThmODhjNzc2ZGZlMzRjODllNmQ5YzU5MWZlMA=="},"user_id":"Mike"}
currentUserName():72:  current_user=<flask_login.AnonymousUserMixin object at 0x7f2f10bff690> 
currentUserName():74
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2016 11:54:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Note that:

1. before the request, the session cookie has the correct username of Mike
2. my `load_user()` function doesn't get called by flask_login
3. When Jinja2 renders the template for /, Flask's `current_user` is now an anonymous user

So, why is flask-login changing my `current_user` from a correct logged-in user, to an anonymous one? And how do I fix this?

FWIW, I'm using Flask (0.10.1), Flask-Login (0.3.2), itsdangerous (0.24).

**Edit:**

My user class is called `Engineer`. It's an SQLAlchemy class that also inherits from Flask-login's `UserMixin`.

```
class Engineer(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'tblEngineers'
    engineerId = Column('EngineerID', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = Column('Username', String())
    password = Column('Password', String())
    firstName = Column('FirstName', String())
    lastName = Column('LastName', String())
    engineer = Column('Engineer', Integer())

    def __repr__(self):
        s = "<Engineer %d %r %r>" % (
            self.engineerId, self.username, self.engineer)
        return s

    #========== stuff Flask-login needs: ==========
    def get_id(self):
        result = unicode(self.username)
        pr("get_id() => %r", result)
        return result
```

Unfortunately the `get_id()` function isn't getting called when flask_login automatically logs me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your User model. You need to make sure the model is returning the proper id you want to use. By default it will load via the id property of the model however I see you are using username. You probably need to add:

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.username
```

You can see an example based on the code you submitted [here.](https://github.com/m1yag1/stack_overflow/blob/master/login.py#L116-L120)

Comment: The username and password are validated in `user = modsal.getUser(un, pw)`. Also, at the moment I'm more concerned with getting it to work **at all** rather than security.

Comment: @PhilHunt, I've updated my answer. I was able to reproduce your problem It is the get_id on your User model. Please check the solution above.

Comment: My `get_id()` function looks like this

    def get_id(self):
            result = unicode(self.username)
            pr("get_id() => %r", result)
            return result

Unfortunately it doesn't get called.

Comment: (Comments here don't format code properly so I've put my `get_id()` function in the main article.)

Comment: that's interesting. I made a sample app based off of your code and was able to get it to work. Have you tried comparing the code with yours? https://github.com/m1yag1/stack_overflow/blob/master/login.py#L116-L120